# Как оформляется "Вместо посвящения" и чем это "вместо" отличается от посвящения?

Tags: оформление-книги

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так сойдёт?

Равнение по правому краю, на кегль меньше основного текста. Но главное - коррелирует (кх-кх!) ли объявленное "вместо" с указанным именем и собственно текстом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Едва ли существует *стандартное* расположение текста для строк, приводимых *в том месте*, где могло бы быть посвящение ("вместо посвящения"). Здесь у автора вместо **посвящения** получилось **обращение** к названному дедушке, о чём он честно предупреждает. В самом *посвящении*, которое может предварять публикацию, ничего таинственного нет (в википедии толкуют, что *посвящение* бывает лицу, группе лиц, его/их памяти и даже отвлечённому понятию). В форме же заголовка "вместо посвящения" выглядело бы несколько вызывающе (= *не буду никому посвящать*, даже упомянутым лицам), в отличие от широко употребляемого "**вместо предисловия**" (это просто предисловие в нестандартной форме; возможно, излишне отвлечённое, о чём предупреждают). Видимо, не случайно по этому словосочетанию сразу находится одноимённый стишок Ахматовой (его содержание отрицает факт посвящения адресату). Поэтому названное здесь словами "вместо посвящения" лишь заменяет то, чего можно было ожидать в силу названного имени; такое предположение читателя сразу отрицается: предисловие не следует здесь рассматривать как *посвящение*. Не исключено, что автор намеренно захотел выровнять текст нестандартным образом, заострив внимание на своём отказе "посвятить".

Comment: Сашко, мне бы простое да-нет: *так* (как есть) можно? Или сделать: *Посвящается дедушке, Константину Макарычу,* а потом - ниже или на другой полосе - написать *Вместо предисловия* и вот этот текстик-крохотульку?

Comment: Я не вижу ничего плохого.